# Converting inline JavaScript to TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have the following inline JavaScript in my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var vm = null;
    $(function () {
       vm = new MyViewModel(); // ViewModel
       ...
    });
    ...
    var data = Scheduler.schedulerToObject(vm.editScheduler());
```

Ajax in html:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '@Url.Action("SetScheduler")',
   data: JSON.stringify(data),
   type: "POST",
   dataType: 'json',           
   success: function (result) {
      if (result.succeeded) {
         $('#edit').modal('hide');
      } 
      else {
         showWrating(result.error);
      }
    },
    error: function (message) {
      toastr.error(message, "Error");
    }
});"
```

How can I convert this to TypeScript?

Comment: Removed your C# tag. Please don't add irrelevant tags. Also, SO is not a code conversion service... please try this on your own.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your code in a new files with a .ts extension. You can then paste in your JavaScript and see where you get compilation errors. To solve the compilation errors, you'll need definition files for the external libraries.

You can get definitions for many libraries on Definitely Typed, such as jQuery.

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

If you get stuck on something specific, post a good question here and we will help you out.

https://stackoverflow.com/faq